# ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: command-line, python, anaconda

I'm trying to schedule some python script with the Windows scheduler. Unfortunately, I run into the following error when I try to execute my script from the Command Prompt:

```
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

The code I'm trying to run is fairly simple and only uses the following imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import datetime as dt
import pyodbc
```

When running the code from Anaconda prompt (and using the desired environment) everything works fine:

```
(scheduler_env) C:\Users\a316283\Desktop\SQLProcessing\ScheduledReality>UpdateScheduledReality.py
```

In Jupyter Notebook (in the same environment) everything works perfect as well.

Running the following in Command Prompt on the other hand side yields:

```
C:\>C:\Users\a316283\.julia\conda\3\envs\scheduler_env\python.exe C:\Users\a316283\Desktop\SQLProcessing\ScheduledReality\UpdateScheduledReality.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a316283\Desktop\SQLProcessing\ScheduledReality\UpdateScheduledReality.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\a316283\.julia\conda\3\envs\scheduler_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Drilling a bit further down and just running python in this environment:

```
C:\Users\a316283\.julia\conda\3\envs\scheduler_env>python.exe
```

Yield a similar error when trying to import numpy:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\a316283\.julia\conda\3\envs\scheduler_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\a316283\.julia\conda\3\envs\scheduler_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

Any advice is more than welcome. Thanks.

*** I tried this in different environments, including my base environment, but I keep running in the same error. I uninstalled en reinstalled numpy and pandas in all my environments, without any result.

EDIT: Solved this problem, try following these steps:

- Run the command prompt and run `python`
- Try to `import pandas` ; you should get the above mentioned error
- Check if you got the following warning upon opening python: *Warning:
  This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
  not been activated. Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
  please see https://conda.io/activation*
- Close python (`exit()`)
- Activate your environment (base in my case): `activate base`
- Run Python scripts

Answer (score 3):

I was getting crazy about the exact same thing. My script was working fine in Spyder AND in CONDA prompt BUT NOT in a standard CMD/PowerShell.
I found [this link in the PowerBI community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/importing-dataframe-with-python-throws-script-error/m-p/546827#M257070) that also presented the same problem.

Everything was correctly installed, checked with `conda list --revisions`.

After digging a bit, I was sure it was a PATH problem.
So, I did these steps:

1. Update Anaconda (`conda update --all`)
2. Manually update the PATH variable in my System Variables with these values:

   `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts`

Now my Python scripts runs from a CMD/PS window without the error 
*ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated anaconda as you described and updated the PATH variable in my System Variables. I couldn't seem to find the 'usr' folder in 'Anaconda3\Library'. Do you have any idea why this could be missing? 
After updating all this CMD execution still does not work.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I installed Anaconda using its wizard, without even changing the installation path, I presume the basic path should be the ones I described, if the installation works fine.

I used this link: https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe